# How do I create several methods in one WSDL and unique attributes in each?

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl

I don't know how to write WSDL specifications.

I tried to do it in Soap UI.

I don't know how to write WSDL specifications.

I tried to do it in Soap UI.

I don't know how to write WSDL specifications.

I tried to do it in Soap UI.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also repeating yourself does not help others to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

this may work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com">

    <!-- Определение элементов данных -->
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema
            targetNamespace="http://www.example.com"
            xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com">
            <!-- ... (как и раньше) ... -->
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <!-- Определение сообщений -->
    <wsdl:message name="RequestMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Method1Request"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ResponseMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Method1Response"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="RequestMessage2">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Method2Request"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ResponseMessage2">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Method2Response"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <!-- Определение операций -->
    <wsdl:portType name="MyPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="Method1">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:RequestMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:ResponseMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="Method2">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:RequestMessage2"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:ResponseMessage2"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <!-- Определение привязок -->
    <wsdl:binding name="MyBinding" type="tns:MyPortType">
        <!-- ... (как и раньше) ... -->
    </wsdl:binding>

    <!-- Определение служб -->
    <wsdl:service name="MyService">
        <wsdl:port name="MyPort" binding="tns:MyBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://www.example.com/MyService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```